# Area and Perimeter GCSE Exam Question. Help Please..

Tags: geometry, area

I need help on this Area and Perimeter Question:
[image]

What I did:
 11 * 7 - 10* 6 - 77-60 = 17

Thank You and Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y+x=7$ and $2y+x=11$

and you get $y=4$ and $x=3$
[image]

the whole area is: 
$4(12)=48$

Comment: Thank You very Much!